# Azure AppService set environment for Blazor application?

Tags: azure, blazor, blazor-webassembly, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I want to deploy a Blazor application (Web assembly) to Azure App Service.

I want to set the environment of the Azure App Service to Development.

I try setting this to Development.

[image]

However after the deployment, it's saying Environment: Production.

[image]

Homepage.razor:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment HostEnvironment

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<p>Environment: @HostEnvironment.Environment</p>
```

Please anyone can suggest on how to set the Environment on Azure App Service to Development, not default as Production.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: There are a few different ways to do this and the original web.config method that I explained isn't my favorite personally, so I figured I'd update.**

**1.** If you deploy with a .NET hosted server, you can add some middleware to set the header for your blazor application like this:

```
// Custom middleware to add the "Blazor-Environment" header
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Blazor-Environment"))
        {
            var environmentName = app.Environment.EnvironmentName;
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Blazor-Environment", environmentName);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

This would go in your Program.cs on your .NET side.

**2.** If you're not using .NET hosting, you can use javascript and define your slots in scripts like this:

```
window.getApiBaseAddress = () => {
    if (window.location.hostname.includes("localhost")) {
        //Local
        return "https://localhost:7272";
    }
    else if (window.location.hostname.includes("testing")) {
        //Testing: some-site-testing.somedomain.com
        return "some-site-testing.somedomain.com";
    }
    else {
        //Prod: some-site.somedomain.com
        return "https://some-site.somedomain.com";
    }
};
```

I used it like this to set the API base address:

```
// Use JS Interop to get base API address
var jsRuntime = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IJSRuntime>();
var apiAddress = new Uri(await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getApiBaseAddress"));
```

Then I set my API base address using this, but you could also use it to retrieve the environment:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDMTokenService>(_ => new DMTokenService(
    _.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenProvider>(),
    apiAddress.ToString() // Pass the base URL directly
));
```

**3.** You can modify your `web.config` to pass the variables in the header.

You can test this manually in Azure by going to your deployment slot and, under development tools, selecting App Service Editor (preview).

This will show you the root directory of your deployed application and you will see that Azure has created a `web.config` for you if one does not exist.

You can add the headers there manually like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Blazor-Environment" value="Development" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This goes inside the `<system.webServer>` tag.

Azure created this one for me (and you can see where I inserted the headers):

[image: Azure Web Config]

Now when you load up your page, your app will load the correct app.{environment}.json file:

[image: Headers]

Depending on how you publish, you may want to create separate web.{environment}.config files:

If using the .pubxml publish feature in Visual Studio IDE, you can do it like this:

1. Add multiple `web.config` files to your project, each designed for a specific environment. You could name them `web.Production.config`, `web.Testing.config`, etc.
2. Make sure to set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of these files to `Do not copy`.
3. Then, in each `.pubxml` file, add a `Target` that will rename the appropriate `web.*.config` to `web.config` during the publish process.

For example, if you have a `Production.pubxml`, you could include:

```xml
<Target Name="WebConfigReplacement" BeforeTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage">
    <Move SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)web.Production.config" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)web.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"/>
</Target>
```

And for a `Testing.pubxml`, you could include:

```xml
<Target Name="WebConfigReplacement" BeforeTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage">
    <Move SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)web.Testing.config" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)web.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"/>
</Target>
```

Remember to change the path `$(ProjectDir)web.Production.config` and `$(ProjectDir)web.Testing.config` to match the actual location of your `web.*.config` files.

This will replace the `web.config` file with the environment-specific one during the publish process. The `web.config` is created again from the `web.config.template` file every time you build the project in your local environment.

NOTE: Be sure to back up your files before trying this, as using the `Move` task will overwrite your files. And always test in a safe environment before deploying to production.

Also, you should exclude your `web.config` file from your source control to prevent accidental commits of environment-specific configs.

Answer (score 0):

The default deployment slot in Azure App Service is the production one. You'll need to setup slots specifically for development or other environments ('staging' is more commonly used). See the [Azure App Service documentation for setting up staging environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) for more information.